# Fox only. Remove search field border

Tags: css

Basic search bar. If search btn clicked with txt field blank border shows up? how to remove?

[image: Demo Pic]

I've tried the basic's border: none, background: trans etc with no success.

Code Pen Demo: 
https://codepen.io/Kryptonite2020/pen/JjPxBPe

Sorry I tried to post the code, but even after all the format issues still wouldn't let me post it?

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">

<div class="search-bar">

   <input type="text" class="input" name="q" required="required" placeholder="&nbsp;">
   <span class="label">Google Search...</span>
   <span class="highlight"></span>
  <div class="search-btn">
   <input type="image" src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/25/56d54b7991e2da2d307eafbd0e8e59b7-full.png"
   onmouseover="this.src='https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/25/647f72cdacd7bc2226c10b2353debbac-full.png';"
   onmouseout="this.src='https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/25/56d54b7991e2da2d307eafbd0e8e59b7-full.png';"/>
  </div>

</div>

</form>
```

To remove txt field border.. Any help much appreciated.

ps - sorry no css.. was so hard to post this as a newbie

Comment: Did you mean Firefox? If so, please add it as a tag instead of a title.

Comment: I don't see the red box in Firefox - https://imgur.com/JARooL4 - but it would have something to do with the HTML5 validation I think.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to paste the code, also which browser you are having this issue.
In chrome, I dont see any border coming through on click/hover. It will be hard to give you a solution without seeing the code.

But from the screenshot, it should be an outline. So you can try making outline: 0; and have a look.

```
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=text]:hover{
  border: 0;,
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys new to forum platforms. After digging around Stacks for a while I found a solution.. Awesome thanks Stacks contributors..

```
[code]
    input:required {
        box-shadow:none;
    }
[/code]
```